# Read text file and format data using python, dict or list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I need help parsing following data from text file and reformating it to the way the output is shown, so it basically counts the state and adds its number in the new column, also it removes duplicate address (if they have same date and IP)

```
Sample Input Data to read


    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        stuck
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync

Output Data to print



11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   success         2
11/11/2015              9.9.9.8   stuck    1
11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   Sync         1
11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   success         4
11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   stuck    3
11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   Sync         2
11/12/2015              9.9.9.8   success         1
```

---

I tried to load my file using following, but failed to reformat it correct.

```
file=open('logfile.txt' , 'r')
contents=file.readlines()

for line in contents:
```

Comment: So you think I should assign each column of my data in one dict?

Comment: i misunderstood the question. probably something like `split_line = line.split()`  and `date = split_line[0]` and `ip = split_line[1]` and so on.

Comment: 'it removes duplicate address (if they have same date and IP)' am I wrong or all the sample data has same IP and date?

Comment: @ThatBird- No they have different IP in last octet, and so are the dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` for this.

```
from collections import Counter
data = '''    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        stuck
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync'''
print('\n'.join('%s %s' % (' '.join(k), v) for k, v in Counter(tuple(f for i, f in enumerate(l.split()) if i != 2) for l in data.split('\n')).items()))
```

This outputs:

```
11/11/2015 9.9.9.9 success 2
11/11/2015 9.9.9.8 stuck 1
11/11/2015 9.9.9.9 Sync 1
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 success 4
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 stuck 3
11/12/2015 9.9.9.8 success 1
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 Sync 2
```

Comment: Good stuff, would you mind like elaborating a bit on last print line, like what each sections intends to do, it will help me as well in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` and `defaultdict` from `collections` module:

```
data_in = """
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        stuck
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/11/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.8   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        stuck
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        success
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
    11/12/2015              9.9.9.9   30s        Sync
"""

import re
from collections import defaultdict

groups = re.findall('([\d/]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\ds]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)', data_in)
d = defaultdict(int)
for g in groups:
    d[(g[0], g[1], g[2], g[3])] += 1

for k, v in d.items():
    s = ' '.join(i for i in k)
    print(f'{s} {v}')
```

Output:

```
11/11/2015 9.9.9.9 30s success 2
11/11/2015 9.9.9.8 30s stuck 1
11/11/2015 9.9.9.9 30s Sync 1
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 30s success 4
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 30s stuck 3
11/12/2015 9.9.9.8 30s success 1
11/12/2015 9.9.9.9 30s Sync 2
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, would you be able to explain me this line?        groups = re.findall('([\d/]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\ds]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)', data_in)

Comment: @Sal This is regular expression. This concrete expression tries to find 4 groups. First group only digits and `/` character, second group digits and `.` character and so on. I made online regexp example here to see what's going on: https://regex101.com/r/aZwnqs/1

Comment: Very helpful, one last thing, is there a way I read above data as a file instead of defining it? I tried using open and file.readlines, but it does not like the formatting. Will appreciate your help?

Comment: @sal use `data_in = open('MY FILENAME', 'r').read()`, it should work.

Comment: Hi I did try that, but it did not like the new format, possibly the formatting is different than what we have earlier.

**Error!**
['Date      IP            Time      State    \n', '\n', '9/1/2013              1.1.1.1   0:10....

  File "C:/Users/sulai/PycharmProjects/MyPythonApp/test2.py", line 28, in <module>
    groups = re.findall('([\d/]+)\s*([\d\.]+)\s*([\ds]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)', data_in)
  File "C:\Users\sulai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object